# disable / remove .NET Framework 3.5 language pack in windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, .net-3.5

Windows 7 comes with the .NET Framework 3.5 already installed. Because I installed the Dutch version of Windows 7, the errors thrown by .NET 3.5 are also in Dutch. Not very practical when debugging in Visual Studio, I want the English exceptions.

In Windows XP this was not a problem, you could uninstall the language pack (Install / Uninstall program). However for some reason MS decided you cannot uninstall the language pack, because it's now part of the operating system.

**What doesn't work:**

- Manually remove .resources files from the framework. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\nl
- Install the Dutch [language pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8489ed13-b831-4855-96f7-dd35e4c02a20&displaylang=en) (it's already installed ofcourse), hoping there would become an uninstall option available.

**What does work:**

- Develop my webapplications in .NET 4.0, because .NET 4.0 is not installed by default with Win 7. This will work eventually...
- Add `<globalization UiCulture="en-US" />` to the web.config. Most of my application are in Dutch so I can't change this setting. Has to be nl-NL.

**How can I remove / disable the Dutch language pack for .NET framework 3.5 on a Dutch Windows 7 machine?**

Comment: i found a solution in this thread, setup the config files:

http://superuser.com/questions/547177/cant-uninstall-reinstall-net-framework-3-5-with-dism

Answer (score 0):

You can actually uninstall an installed language pack from Windows 7. You have to open "Install or uninstall display languages" from the Control Panel. Just write e.g. "uninstall language pack" in the Windows 7 Start Menu to access this.

Comment: Hi, I think you mean a Windows Language Pack, not a .NET framework language pack. Either way, this option is not available for me.

Comment: You are right, I meant the Windows Language Packs that are available in the Enterprise and Ultimate versions of Windows 7, which did the trick for me since I had an English version of Windows. If you have a non-English version of Windows this solution does not apply, as in your case.